# Drawerlayout intercepting all the clicks

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm currently making an app and is facing this problem:

after I created fragments in a drawermenu my floating button doesn't react to anything anymore. I have asked this question on another forum and their answer was that my Drawerlayout was intercepting the clicks. How can I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Use DrawerLayout as root container for activity -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false">



<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:elevation="4dp"/>
<!-- Layout to contain contents of main body of screen (drawer will slide over this) -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
   >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/upper_section"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="225dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg">


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            app:fabSize="normal" />




    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer) how to implement the drawer layout correctly. You seem to have some unwanted layout settings. Try copying the entire layout and replace only what's inside the frame layout :)